# Does Apollo Server work with GraphQL Tools stitchSchemas?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, graphql-tools

According to [Apollo docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration-two-dot/)

- *"Apollo Server 2 exports all of graphql-tools, so
  makeExecutableSchema and other functions can be imported directly
  from Apollo Server."*
- *"Apollo Server is able to accept a schema that has been enabled by
  graphql-tools"*

However, I've just noticed  I can't directly import [stitchSchemas](https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/stitch-type-merging/) from apollo-server (I've been using it from @graphql-tools/stitch), and am hours deep in problems that aren't making sense.

Does Apollo work with stitchSchemas or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `stitchSchemas` with Apollo Server, but you should install the latest version of `graphql-tools` and import `stitchSchemas` from `graphql-tools` instead of `apollo-server`.

You can use the latest version of `graphql-tools` to build a `GraphQLSchema` object, whether through `stitchSchemas`, `makeExecutableSchema` or some other utility. You can then initialize ApolloServer using this schema:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({ schema })
```

Comment: Thanks. Does this include type merging? I was able to use the schema resulting from stitchSchemas before but each subschema would only return data from itself, any other fields were null.

Comment: That sounds like an issue with how you're using `stitchSchemas` in the first place. If you have a function that returns a GraphQLSchema object, that should work with Apollo, GraphQL Helix or pretty much any other GraphQL server library.

Comment: Further testing confirms the type merging isn't happening on other platforms or clients either. The problem must be somewhere else.